# Load a symbol in SnapSVG

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

So I just came across [Snap SVG](http://snapsvg.io) and I see it has support to load .svg files via AJAX.  Does SnapSVG have any support for loading pre-defined symbols?  For example, I have the following code at the top of my document:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display: none;">
  <symbol id="idbar-menu-button" viewbox="0 0 31 23">
    <rect id="topRect" y="0" width="32" height="5"/>
    <rect id="midRect" y="9" width="32" height="5"/>
    <rect id="botRect" y="18" width="32" height="5"/>
  </symbol>
</svg>
```

Yes, it's a simple hamburger button.  I want to animate it.  The whole reason I'm switching to SVG is to avoid unnecessary HTTP requests for things.

Snap.svg's documentation and every example I can find says that you need to load the SVG via http request, rather than using any kind of symbol already defined somewhere.

Is there a function somewhere that I can't find in the docs, or is this not possible using the current implementation?

Comment: Not quite sure what you are asking..have you just tried using the load() method ? Eg http://svg.dabbles.info/snaptut-load-animate rereading, is the svg inline you mean ? If so, you can just var el = Snap('#idbar-menu-button') and use el.doSomething()

Answer (score 0):

Snap.svg recently added support for svg symbols (as of version 0.4).

Comment: Cool, I'll give it a try when I get a chance